# How to find a business consultant that would ensure that all your business activities are legal and compliant with all regulations?

Tags: united-states, small-business, california, sole-proprietorship, regulation

I have been helping a friend of mine who is owner of a small Beauty Salon. In the last year I have been helping her with so many legal-related things that it is taking too much of my time and I want to recommend her to seek professional help - unfortunately, I am not sure what professional I should refer her to, because there are so many regulations in California for small business owner that I don't think there is one person that would "know it all". But I am still asking this question just in case there is such person or at least if there exists website that would advice you on what you should do. :)

To give few examples of problems that she has to deal:

1. Ensure that her salon complies `IRS`,`FTB` and `EDD` requirements in case she gets audited;
2. Ensure that her salon complies with latest `Barbering and Cosmetology board` requirements in case she gets audited;
3. Ensure that her salon complies `Board of Equalization` requirements in case she gets audited;
4. Ensure that her salon complies with city and county requirements in case she gets audited by `county's tax assessor`.
5. I probably missed other entities that could come to her salon any day and audit her, for example, `fire department`, `consumer affairs department` ...?

**Are there professionals who specialize on consulting small business owners from A-Z so that business would be compliant with all regulations? What are the keywords to "google" them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a specific service recommendation is off-topic, but the question of what type of professional you need seems on-topic to me.  You may be looking for more than one professional in this case, but you could try these to start your search:

- Attorney specializing in business law. (I know of a couple that do specialize in small business in CA, so they exist.)
- Tax attorney
- Certified public accountant (CPA)

Different people do things differently, but I think it would be pretty common to have a relationship (i.e. contract, retainer agreement, at least have met the person in case you have an "emergency") with a business law attorney and either a CPA or tax attorney.  You may try not to use them too much to keep costs down, but you don't want to be searching for one *after* you have an issue. You want to know who you're going to call and may establish at least a basis working relationship.